# Rails asset_host protocol relative issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am setting the asset host in our production environment to the following: config.action_controller.asset_host = `"//assets%d-*****.com"` However the resulting urls that appear on the front end are `"http:////assets1-*****.com"` which is causing an issue in Internet Explorer. We do need the protocol relative url because we use both http and https on the application.

This works fine in other browsers like chrome, im guessing because it knows thats not the correct url. Anybody have any suggestions??

Update 1: I am doing this same thing in a different app but it is running a different version of Rails. The app that has the issue is running rails 3.0.4 and its working in another app running 3.1.11. Did something change in how asset_host works?

Comment: So I believe I found the issue here. Rails 3.0.4 does not support using protocol relative urls in the asset host. So the fix is to use the following:

<pre><code>
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
    "#{request.protocol}assets#{ ['0','1','2','3'].sample }-*****.com"
  }
</code></pre>

Comment: I'm seeing similar issues today on rails 4.0.0

Comment: I created a new conversation about the specific and similar issue I'm seeing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160348/asset-host-and-relative-protocol-urls-being-changed-to-http